# matplotlib plot not showing if called as a function:

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, math, symbolic-math

I have the following code which sort of works in that when the function is called I get the three plots that I have hard-coded show up:

```
def Function(n):
    def f_x(n):
        Code
        return output_0, output_1
    def x_t(n):
        Code
        return output_0, output_1
    def z(n):
        Code
        return output_0, output_1, output_2

    plt.subplot(221)
    plt.title("f(x)")
    plt.xlabel(x)
    plt.ylabel(y)
    plt.scatter(x_list,f_x(n)[1])
 
    plt.subplot(223)
    plt.title("t(x)")
    plt.xlabel(x)
    plt.ylabel(t),
    plt.scatter(x_t(n)[0],x_t(n)[0])
  
    plt.subplot(222)
    plt.title("z(t)")
    plt.xlabel("t")
    plt.ylabel("z(t)")
    plt.scatter(x_t(n)[0], z(n)[2])

    plt.tight_layout()
```

but I don't want to get the plot every time I run the function to get my values (which is useless, most of the time, anyways), so I did the following:

```
def Function(n):
    def f_x(n):
        Code
        return output_0, output_1
    def x_t(n):
        Code
        return output_0, output_1
    def z(n):
        Code
        return output_0, output_1, output_2

    def plot(n): 
        def f_plot(n):
            plt.subplot(221)
            plt.title("f(x)")
            plt.xlabel(x)
            plt.ylabel(y)
            plt.scatter(x_list,f_x(n)[1])
 
            plt.subplot(223)
            plt.title("t(x)")
            plt.xlabel(x)
            plt.ylabel(t),
            plt.scatter(x_t(n)[0],x_t(n)[0])
  
            plt.subplot(222)
            plt.title("z(t)")
            plt.xlabel("t")
            plt.ylabel("z(t)")
            plt.scatter(x_t(n)[0], z(t)(n))

            plt.tight_layout()
        return f_plot(n)


    return plot(n), output_2_1, output_2_2, output_3
```

Unfortunately, what i wrote above doesn't work and I don't know what the issue is. By the way, I also tried to add an extra bit of code to sort of force publish the graph but that didn't work either:

`print(Function(n)[0])`

Also tried,

`plt.show()`

The first one shows the plot both with and without `plt.show()` while the second one doesn't both with and without it. One more thing, I checked each subfunction within the main function to see whether those functions are problematic byt the following codes:

`len(x_t(n)[i]), type (x_t(n)[i],` etc. To make sure the outputs are:

1. Lists
2. Dimentionally equally for each domain and co-domain.

Fortunately, they were all good, and, hence, I narrowed down the issue to matplotlib code.

Comment: `output_0`, `output_1` and `output_2` are only defined within the scope of the inner functions, so they don't have meaning in the `return` statement of the outer function.

Comment: @slothrop Sorry about that, that was sloppy writing on my end. The outer function has a different output, not necesssrily calling the output of the inner functions.

Comment: How does it "not work"? If you're running this within a Python script, looks like you're missing a `plt.show()` at the end of your `f_plot` function. It should just about work in a notebook environment.

Comment: @DominikStańczak I agree, it should but it doesn't. I tried, both with and without, ```plt.show()```, but the first one shows the plot, both with and without, ```plt.show()``` while the second doesn't. I don't know the reason for the disparate outputs of the two, theoretically at least, similar codes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit at a loss, but you could try rewriting it like this, using the object-oriented matplotlib interface. This means you won't have any weird variable scoping issues, since instead of explicitly creating the `Figure` in the background, you explicitly move it out of the nested function. The output may look a little different with the `subplots` call, but I assume you can adjust once you have anything visible.

```py
def Function(n):
    def f_x(n):
        Code
        return output_0, output_1
    def x_t(n):
        Code
        return output_0, output_1
    def z(n):
        Code
        return output_0, output_1, output_2

    def plot(n): 
        def f_plot(n):
            fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)

            ax = axes[0,0]
            ax.set_title("f(x)")
            ax.set_xlabel(x)
            ax.set_ylabel(y)
            ax.scatter(x_list,f_x(n)[1])  # I assume x_list is defined somewhere
 
            ax = axes[0, 1]
            ax.set_title("t(x)")
            ax.set_xlabel(x)
            ax.set_ylabel(t),
            ax.scatter(x_t(n)[0],x_t(n)[0])
  
            ax = axes[1, 0]
            ax.set_title("z(t)")
            ax.set_xlabel("t")
            ax.set_ylabel("z(t)")
            ax.scatter(x_t(n)[0], z(t)(n))

            fig.tight_layout()
            return fig
        return f_plot(n)


    return plot(n), output_2_1, output_2_2, output_3

fig, output1, output2, output3 = Function(n)
fig.show()
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, unfortunately, that too didn't work. At this point I will probably abandon the subplot function altogether, and plot each graph individually. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why to define a function inside other functions, maybe you intended you use `class`?

Then the modified code would look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
class Function():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def f_x(n,self):
        Code
        return output_0, output_1
    def x_t(n,self):
        Code
        return output_0, output_1
    def z(n,self):
        Code
        return output_0, output_1, output_2

    def f_plot(n,self):
        plt.subplot(221)
        plt.title("f(x)")
        plt.xlabel(x)
        plt.ylabel(y)
        plt.scatter(x_list,self.f_x(n)[1])
 
        plt.subplot(223)
        plt.title("t(x)")
        plt.xlabel(x)
        plt.ylabel(t),
        plt.scatter(self.x_t(n)[0],self.x_t(n)[0])
  
        plt.subplot(222)
        plt.title("z(t)")
        plt.xlabel("t")
        plt.ylabel("z(t)")
        plt.scatter(self.x_t(n)[0], self.z(t)(n))

        plt.tight_layout()
```

Seeing you defined `f_plot()` inside `plot()` I'm also assuming you want to plot multiple other graphs. If so, then you could define a `plot()` Class inside the `Function()` Class (I forgot if that works though, if it doesn't work just define another function in the `Function` class, but I remember it should work)

To call the functions, you would need to initialise the `Function()` Class like:

```
function = Function()
```

And then to call the other functions you would need to do something like:

```
function.f_x(n) #You would input something here!
function.x_t(n)
function.z(n)
function.f_plot(n)
```

Again, it could be a bug with your IDE or something, you could also try saving the graph somewhere in your device using `plt.savefig("FileName.png")`

Comment: I don't understand why defining the functions within a class would fare better than defining the function within a function. The reason why I have functions within a function is that I will call it within another function later down the line. Thank you for the input though.